# Somar 2 arrays com índices iguais

Tags: php

Tenho um array em uma `$_SESSION['Carrinho']`:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Produto] => ENH1264-1 
                       [Quantidade] => 2 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [Produto] => ENH1264-2 
                       [Quantidade] => 3 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [Produto] => ENH1264-6 
                       [Quantidade] => 1 ) 
      )
```

Gostaria de adicionar novos valores a este array. Tenho este segundo array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Produto] => ENH1264-6 
                       [Quantidade] => 5 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [Produto] => ENH1264-1 
                       [Quantidade] => 8 ) 
      )
```

Existe alguma maneira, sem sair fazendo diversos foreach comparando os resultados, gerando novos arrays? Alguma maneira simplificada?

O resultado esperado seria:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Produto] => ENH1264-1 
        [Quantidade] => 10 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Produto] => ENH1264-2 
        [Quantidade] => 3
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [Produto] => ENH1264-6 
        [Quantidade] => 6
    ) 
)
```

veja que os produtos que são iguais tiveram suas quantidades somadas. Caso no segundo array exista um produto que não tenha no primeiro, adiciona como novo índice.

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Tem como colocar na pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss feito!

Comment: Então o que quer não é somar elementos com índices iguais, como diz o título, mas, sim, somar os itens de mesmo nome em `Produto`?

Comment: seria isso mesmo! Caso tenham o mesmo value no index "produto", somar as indexes "quantidade"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pretende algo simples pode-se basear em [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para mapear um array de produtos nos seus nomes e de seguida pesquisar o produto com [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php). Se encontrar o produto atualiza a quantidade, caso contrário adiciona uma nova entrada ao array.

Exemplo de implementação da lógica acima descrita:

```
$obterProduto = function($p) { return $p["Produto"]; };

foreach ($compras as $compra){
    $posicao = array_search($compra["Produto"], array_map($obterProduto, $produtos));
    if ($posicao === false){ //se não existe adiciona
        $produtos[] = $compra;
    }
    else { //se existe aumenta apenas a quantidade
        $produtos[$posicao]["Quantidade"] += $compra["Quantidade"]; 
    }
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/6fOCJ0)

Comment: Isac, tentei desta maneira e funcionou perfeitamente! :)

Answer (score -1):

pelo que entendi é possível fazer assim também:

```
<?php

/*Obtendo Produto via POST e armazendo em array.*/
$Dados = array([Produto] => $_POST['produto'], 
               [Quantidade] => $_POST['quantidade']);

/*Se o Carrinho ainda não foi configurado, adicione os dados a ele.*/
if (!isset($_SESSION['Carrinho']){
    $_SESSION['Carrinho'] = array($Dados);
}
else{
    /*Senao verifique se já existe o produto dentro dele.*/
    if(in_array($Dados['Produto'], $_SESSION['Carrinho']){

        /*Se existe percorra o carrinho, encontre e acumule a quantidade*/
        foreach($_SESSION['Carrinho'] as $multi){
            $multi[quantidade] += $Dados['Quantidade']
        }
    }
    /*se o produto é novo adicione ele no proximo indice do carrinho*/
    else{
        $_SESSION['Carrinho'] = array_fill(count(Dados['Produto']), 1, $Dados);
    }
}

/*Limpa o array DADOS*/
unset($Dados);

?>
```

Comment: Porque votar contra uma resposta simples? O que tem de errado?

Comment: Fora a sintaxe errada, a lógica não faz sentido em alguns pontos: por exemplo, `Dados['Produto'] = array($Dados)`, por quê armazenar `$Dados` nele mesmo? Se foi definido como *array*, por quê converter para *array*?

Comment: nem notei a questão do Dados['Produto'] = array($Dados), mais consertei. Acabei de editar

Comment: Agora só falta testar e corrigir os erros de sintaxe.

Comment: qual a sintaxe que esta incorreta?